# Did not get National Insurance Number whilst living in the UK

Tags: uk-citizens

My wife lived in the UK for 9 years before settling in Canada. She did not work during that time because she was looking after the children while I was in full time employment in the UK. She did not apply for the NI number, but was receiving "family allowance" for our children who were born in the UK.

How can we track her "family allowance" record information? and possible other information to support her stay in the UK?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the banks statements from when they made deposits?

Comment: Putting on hold until questions are clarified